# Infinities on null sets

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a conceptual question!

Why is it that (e.g.) $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} dx$ doesn't converge.
I'm stuck in the following way of thinking about it:

Since the problematic part is $\int_0^\epsilon \frac{1}{x} dx$, the problem potentially only exits on a null set, but null sets shouldn't matter for integration... so what is wrong with my way of thinking about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking in the Riemann sense, then the function must be well defined in $[0,1]$. Clearly at $x=0$ it is not.

In the extended (or improper) Riemann sense where $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx$ may be understood as $\lim_{c\to0}\int_c^1\frac{1}{x}dx$, the integral (before limits) evaluates to $-\log(c)$ which diverges to $\infty$ as $c$ approaches $0$.

You mentioned that the problem is on a NULL set. It's clearly not. The problem is still there even when you try to evaluate approaching limits.

Case in point, consider instead $\int_0^1\log(x)dx$. What do you think happens here, noting that $\lim_{x\to0}x\log(x)=0$?